# Vue styling components

Tags: css, vue.js, components, styles

I have a basic vue  component. It looks like this:

```js
<script>
export default {
 props: {
  source: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
  }
 },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="imageItem">
    <img class="image" :data-srcset="source" />
    <p> this is some text </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

What I struggle to achieve is, when I load the component in the parent that looks something like this:

```
<imageItem :source="source" />
```

I want to be able to customize the component styles. For example something like this:

```
<imageItem :source="source" :textColor="red" />
```

I'm guessing I should do it with props also but its not working as expected.

Can someone share a proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <script>
export default {
    props: {
        source: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        style:{
            type: String,
            required:true
        }            
    },
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="imageItem">
    <img class="image" :data-srcset="source" :style="style" />
    <p> this is some text </p>
 </div>
</template>
```

And then in the prop: "color:red"

```
<imageItem :source="source" :style="color : red" />
```